# open() "" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

When I request a link `http://abc.example.com/images/default-thumbnail.jpg` a 404 error occurs while seeing the log file output `[error] 1244#0: *1 open() "/tmp/upload-dir/images/default-thumbnail.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory),`

But in fact this file is there,And the authority is 777

```
[root@localhost nginx]# ll /tmp/upload-dir/images/default-thumbnail.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7592 6月  21 2016 /tmp/upload-dir/images/default-thumbnail.jpg
```

Nginx configuration：

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    sendfile off;

    listen 80;

    server_name abc.example.com;

    access_log  /www/abc/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log   /www/abc/logs/nginx-error.log;

    root /tmp/upload-dir;

    location /images/ {
        autoindex on;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should also check the permissions of the surrounding directories.

Comment: `/tmp/upload-dir` permissions are `drwxrwxrwx 4 nginx nginx 4096 April 22 10:15 upload-dir`, I really can not think of where there is no authority, I use the root user to start Nginx

Comment: Are you using an OS with additional security policies, such as CentOS/SELinux?

Comment: I found the reason, ROOT point to the path can not be in the temporary directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Terrence said: Nginx alias path Cannot be a temporary path. eg:/tmp/**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already dealt with this question.

Comment: I have been trying for more than 4 hours just to find out that I can't use `/tmp` for the files. thank you saved the rest of my day:)